# Python 3.11 aiohttp Strange AssertionError

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp

I have an API in python using aiohttp framework, but in the production sometimes I am getting an strange error. And not able to get out of it. I have read all my code 2-3 times. But didn't found any error.

My server is having a active connection with Firestore and MongoDB both.
For production, I am using Railway.app
I am using `3.8.5` version of `aiohttp`

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-37026' coro=<RequestHandler.start() done, defined at /opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py:462> exception=AssertionError()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py", line 505, in start
request = self._request_factory(message, payload, self, writer, handler)
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_app.py", line 446, in _make_request
return _cls(
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_request.py", line 811, in __init__
super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_request.py", line 188, in __init__
assert transport is not None
AssertionError
```

Kindly help me out getting out of it.

Comment: Try to create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show it as properly formatted code in the question.

Comment: Hello @MichaelButscher, thanks for your suggestion but I am getting the error at an random ways. Not able to get any way to regenerate the error.